# Bind to a selected item of the foreach binding with knockout.js 

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout.js and the ko.mapping plugin to bind a list of json object to an html grid. Lets call each item a card (simplified example below)

```
{
    "card": [
        {
            "Id": "cards/1",
            "category": "Demo",
            "title": "Card 1",
            "description": "bla bla",
            "picture": "demo1.jpg ",
            "madeBy": "user/1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "cards/2",
            "category": "Demo",
            "title": "Card 2",
            "description": "bla bla",
            "picture": "demo2.jpg",
            "madeBy": "user/2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I bind each elemet like this:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: card">
    <span data-bind="text:title"></span>
    <a data-bind='click: show'><img data-bind="attr:{src: picture}" /></a>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a card, I would like to show the selected card in a different div (outside of the **foreach**) with some more properties from the selected json object

Who do I bind to one selected card from the view model?

I am trying something like (but not getting any data):

```
<h1 data-bind="text: $data.title"> </h1>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to do this by tracking the selected card on the ViewModel that holds the cards. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWKav/) demonstrating this simply. Here is the modified HTML and JS (this has been simplified for the purpose of a demo, and I'm not using mapping, but you get the idea):

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cards">
    <span data-bind="text:title"></span>
    <a data-bind='click: $parent.selectedCard'>ImagePlaceholder</a>
    </br>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: selectedCard">
    <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
    <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var ViewModel = function(cards) {
    this.cards = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(cards, function(c) {return new Card(c);})
    );
    this.selectedCard = ko.observable();
};
```

Note that the `click` setting the selected card directly, without needing to use wrapper "show" function. Since observables *are* functions, we can skip that step (unless of course you need to do more in the show function).

Comment: Thank you. I like the simplicity of your solution. I had to use the show wrapper to do some more. Is seems that the selected-card is then sent as a parameter to the function automatically. Is that correct?
I use: <a data-bind='click: zoom'>
and:
    function zoom(card) {
        //Some more
        self.selectedCard(card);
    }
Just trying to understand what is happening :)

Comment: It is sent as a parameter. You should read this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/